# Strip text from timestamp and convert to consistent datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

I have a `pandas` dataframe with a string column representing a date/time. The `date` column can have various different timezone endings such as BST, UTC, +01 etc. I don't know *a priori* which endings each date may have. I've only shown three for illustration purposes.

```py
data = {'Name': ['Bob', 'Mary','Alice'],
        'Age': [21, 19, 20],
        'Date': ['2022-07-07 16:43 (+01)', '2022-07-07 16:43 (UTC)',
                   '2022-07-07 16:43 (BST)']}
  
# Convert the dictionary into DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age', 
                                 'Date'])
```

Dataframe:

```
Name   Age  Date
Bob    21   2022-07-07 16:43 (+01)
Mary   19   2022-07-07 16:43 (UTC)
Alice  20   2022-07-07 16:43 (BST)
```

Does a general method exist to remove the various suffixes from the date and convert it to a standard timezone (let's say UTC)?

Comment: You want to convert to datetime data type, and the date/time should be UTC, is that correct? `+01` means a UTC offset of one hour? Are there other kinds of offset specifiers?

Comment: Not that I can see from the data I currently have available to me. But I'm assuming it's possible, so wanted to catch all combinations, if at all possible. And yes, I believe `+01` means UTC + 1 hour. Ugh dates!

Comment: The problem isn't the handling of dates, it's what people think makes a good representation of date, time and time zone in a string ^^ Just take "BST": there are [multiple time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) that can be abbreviated like that. So you as a programmer will have to *define* what is what...

Comment: Thanks @FObersteiner. My ignorance of timezone abbreviations being laid bare here. I didn't realise that the abbreviations are not unique.

Comment: the `tzinfos` keyword for dateutil's parser is a common way to handle this - but it still requires you to define what should be done, no magic here (no, I don't think `fuzzy` is your friend ;-)). I'd extract all the tz specifiers (see the regex I use in my answer for cleanup), call a .unique, and then derive the tz mapping dictionary based on that output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dateutil.parser.parse` with `fuzzy=True` right out of the box or with a minor modification.

Fuzzy:

```py
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> time = '2022-07-07 16:43 (+01)'
>>> dateutil.parser.parse(time, fuzzy=True)
...: datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 7, 16, 43, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 3600))
```

Remove parentheses then call

```py
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> time = '2022-07-07 16:43 (+01)'
>>> dateutil.parser.parse(time.replace(')', '').replace('(', ''))
...: datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 7, 16, 43, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 3600))
```

A more efficient function to parse for a big dataset could be like:

```py
def parse_datetime(time: str) -> datetime.datetime:
    parsable_time = time.translate({ord('('): None,
                        ord(')'): None})
    return dateutil.parser.parse(parsable_time)
```

The rational is you `parse(..., fuzzy=True)` is quiet general and can parse things like "Today is January 1, 2047 at 8:21:00AM" properly, in fact the sentence is from the docstring of `parse(..., fuzzy=True)`, it does quiet a bit of book keeping to carry out such amazing task, you don't need that, so getting rid of parentheses could be more effective if you are running it on a sufficiently big dataset in pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way how you could deal with that input in pandas, also making use of dateutil's parser, but setting the [tzinfos](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse) keyword.

```py
import pandas as pd
import dateutil

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Name': ['Bob', 'Mary','Alice'],
     'Age': [21, 19, 20],
     'Date': ['2022-07-07 16:43 (+01)', '2022-07-07 16:43 (UTC)', '2022-07-07 16:43 (BST)']},
     )

# cleanup
df["Date"] = df["Date"].str.replace("\((.+)\)", "\\1", regex=True)

# first go: parse with "standard" parser, inferring format
df["datetime"] = df["Date"].apply(dateutil.parser.parse)

# now we still have "unparsed" tz:
df["datetime"]
0    2022-07-07 16:43:00+01:00 # was +01 => ok
1    2022-07-07 16:43:00+00:00 # was UTC => ok
2          2022-07-07 16:43:00 # bad...
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

---

```py
# second go...
# where there is no tz set:
m = df["datetime"].apply(lambda t: t.tzinfo is None)
# define time zones
tzinfos = {'BST': dateutil.tz.gettz("Europe/London")}
# ...so we can parser ambiguous stuff like BST
df.loc[m, "datetime"] = df["Date"][m].apply(dateutil.parser.parse, tzinfos=tzinfos)

df["datetime"]
0    2022-07-07 16:43:00+01:00
1    2022-07-07 16:43:00+00:00
2    2022-07-07 16:43:00+01:00
Name: datetime, dtype: object # notice the data type of the series

# now to UTC:
df["UTC"] = df["datetime"].apply(lambda t: t.astimezone(dateutil.tz.UTC))

df["UTC"]
0   2022-07-07 15:43:00+00:00
1   2022-07-07 16:43:00+00:00
2   2022-07-07 15:43:00+00:00
Name: UTC, dtype: datetime64[ns, tzutc()] # datetime64 dtype now :)
```

---

***Notes***

- you need all the `apply`s because you're dealing with mixed UTC offsets in one Series. pandas' `dt` accessor can only handle a single UTC offset / time zone in one Series
- you can skip the first go and the masking step in the second go if you also define `+01` for example in the tzinfos mapping